# HT Access https and .co.uk to .uk

Tags: .htaccess

I'm going around in circles with this and could do with someone guiding me through it .

I am trying to redirect any call to .co.uk or uk, as well as http to https:// , with the added complication of codeigniter and removing /index.php.

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But access to http://example.uk does not redirect a) to https.. and b) seems to break any CSS links

http://www.example.co.uk seems to redirect to http://www.example.uk/www.example.co.uk

Really can't get my head around this.. would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to always redirect to https://www.planandshop.uk/ I think you don't need to bother with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

since you are explicitly redirecting to https://www.example.uk at the end anyway. Just have to make sure that the final rule will match.
To handle both example.co.uk and example.uk you could write the rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example(\.co)?\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Just like you made the www. optional.

Comment: thanks.. yes I had been trying this but I was getting 'too many redirects' I actually think it was something to do with my cache although didn't realise HT Access was cached?